# Is this SAML SSO implementation correct?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

I have a site say **www.e1.com**. **www.e1.com is Service Provider**. Whenever I click a service in it, I am redirected to a **Identity provider, say www.e2.com**. Before that,In service provider(www.e1.com) I will check if any cookie is set for the user. For the first time there will be no cookie so it will send empty SessionId value. Thus, I am sending a SAML Request to www.e2.com along with with no id(as no cookie is set. Cookie contains Id)

Now in www.e2.com i.e.In identity provider,I will check whether www.e1.com has sent any Id value. If it is null I will create a session Id and store it in database(In www.e2.com). Then I will redirect browser to my Authentication page where User's Name and password will be asked and accordingly he will be authenticated. If the authentication is successfull, I will redirect browser to Service provider(www.e1.com) with SAML Response which contains session Id.

**Now in Service provider the SessionId value will be stored in Cookie and browser will be redirected to consumer service page(service page the user wants to access)**.

Now if the same user wants to access some other service from same Service provider
(within the session), the browser will obviously send the SessionId in Cookie along with the request SAML. Identity Provider will check the SessionId value in his database, If its there in its database then it will give direct access to service to user without entering login credential as the user is already authenticated for the session.

**Is this the right way to achieve Single Sign On with SAML?** or
**If this method has flaws, Can you explain those flaws?**
*Thanks in advance :)*

Answer (score 15):

Your understanding is not quite correct :)

Here is the flow:

1. User tries to access a protected resource on the SP. SP checks if the
   user has a local (and authenticated session). If not it generates a
   SAML `<AuthRequest>` which includes a random id. The SP then redirects
   the user to the IDP with this AuthnRequest.
2. The IDP will check if the user has a local authenticated session. If
   not it will authenticate the user The IDP will send an `AuthResponse` 
   back to the SP with an `inReplyTo` attribute which matches the id sent by
   the SP in it's `AuthnRequest`
3. The SP will then create a local session. Subsequent requests to the
   SP will not involve the IDP unless a) The session expires or b) the SP
   receives a `SingleLogout` message from the IDP

Comment: In your 2 .point you said that "The IDP will send an AuthResponse back to the SP with an inReplyTo attribute which matches the id sent by the SP in it's AuthnRequest". You meant that the IDP will redirect the user to SP right with this AthResponse, right?

Comment: Hi Ashwin, the short answer is yes you are correct. The longer answer is that it depends on the SAML binding. In the case of the redirect biding the user's browser will be redirected back to the SP with the AuthResponse. In the case of the post binding the users browser will make a POST request to the SP with this AuthResponse. Finally in the case of the artefact binding the user will be redirected to the SP with an artefact id. The SP will then query the IDP to get the AuthResponse using this artefact id

Comment: The redirect binding and the artefact binding I understood. But how will you make a post redirect. A redirect only uses get method. Then how will you redirect the user with the response in post?

Comment: The user is presented with an HTML page containing a form with a hidden field. The action of this form is set to point to the SP. The user then submits this form either by clicking a button or more likely using some javascript which fires during the onDomLoaded event. In this case the user POSTs back to the SP although he probably didn't realize this happened. This is actually the most common IDP->SP binding, it's the one we use by default

Comment: Is it wrong to add the response to a redirect using get method. Presently that is what we are using.

Comment: No there is nothing wrong with that, the only problem is that you are limited by the maximum length of the query string which may prevent you from passing a detailed response (e.g. containing SAML attributes). There is also a potential security risk because the SAML response may be stored in server log files.

Comment: "There is also a potential security risk because the SAML response may be stored in server log files" I did not get this part

Comment: @TobyHobson.. I have a question please.. How the SP receives a SingleLogout message from the IDP

I made a logout from the IdP and waited for a call to the consume page in my SP but nothing has been sent!

Comment: In 3rd point you mentioned *unless a) The session expires or b) the SP receives a SingleLogout* if I manually  clear browser history then how can I manage?

Comment: @Ashwin The Application servers (which are usually Tomcat, Websphere, Glassfish) are generally frontend by Web Servers (like Apache HTTPd, Nginx, HAProxy). The Web Servers have the access_log files which log what and all have been accessed by its clients. As part of that, the entire URI (or URL) along with the query parameters are logged. When your query parameters contain such sensitive info, these logs become a threat as they are one of the main targets attackers focus on.

Comment: @Homam your IdP configuration for the SAML SP should contain the SLO URL. if it's not configured, or configured but not invoked by the IdP, you should check with the team that maintains the IdP

Comment: @Hearty if your browser cookies are cleared, it's as good as wiping the session from the user's perspective. But the (IdP or SP) Server doesn't know yet until the session has timed out. If you have a burning need to support this scenario, your application will need to listen to [`cookiechangeevent`](https://patrickkettner.github.io/cookie-change-events/#cookiechangeevent) and trigger the SLO URL.